# ImageView above BottomAppBar

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

I need to place a picture between the top border of the parent and the top border of the `BottomAppBar`, but when I do this, my `BottomAppBar` does not look right:

[image]

**My layout**

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView
            android:src="@color/colorGraySuper"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/containerBottomAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp">


        </ImageView>


    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerBottomAppBar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <com.fromsakuraso13.waifu.presentation.views.RoundedBottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/navigationBottom"
            app:fabAlignmentMode="end"
            app:leftTopCornerSize="10dp"
            app:rightTopCornerSize="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_navigation_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />



        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccentLight"
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/navigationBottom" />


    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always use `CoordinatorLayout` as the container layout housing other layouts(like `ConstraintLayout` or `RelativeLayout`) which should be used as parent layout for constraining other views as mentioned [here](https://medium.com/@DarishJoy/constraintlayout-vs-coordinatorlayout-brief-comparison-aa1e64292462). However, any views which require effects like dodging `Snackbar` for `FAB` or collapsing toolbar with `AppBarLayout` should be placed as direct child of the `CoordinatorLayout`.

For your case, I would suggest placing the views as follows:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>

    <ConstraintLayout>    //you can skip this if there are no other views except ImageView
        <ImageView/>
    </ConstraintLayout>

    <RoundedBottomActionBar/>
    <FloatingActionButton/>

</CoordinatorLayout/>
```